# ハッシュの要素抽出について

Tags: ruby

プログラムを実行した際の結果が

```
{"a"=> "1", "b"=>"2","c"=>"3", "d"=>"4", "e"=>"5", "g"=>"6"}
```

と複数のハッシュで返ってきた場合に、bとeの結果のみを抽出したい場合はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

基礎的な事なのかもしれませんが、rubyを初めて間もないため上手くいきません。
教えて頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: select メソッドを使うと良いかもしれません。`h.select{|k,v| ["b","e"].include?(k)}`

Comment: ありがとうございます。今までselectの使い方がいまいち分かりませんでしたがやっと分かりました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結果が `x` という変数に代入されているとします。

```
x = {"a"=> "1", "b"=>"2","c"=>"3", "d"=>"4", "e"=>"5", "g"=>"6"}
```

`x` においてキー `"b"` に紐付いている値を得るには、`x["b"]` と書きます。

```
x["b"]  # => "2" が返ってきます
```

`x` から `"b"` と `"e"` の部分だけ持った別のハッシュを作るには、`Hash#slice` が使えます (Ruby 2.5.0 以降)。

```
x.slice("b", "e")  # => {"b"=>"2", "e"=>"5"} が返ってきます。
```

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。sliceは2.5.0以降しか使えなかったんですね。助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

```
{"a"=> "1", "b"=>"2","c"=>"3", "d"=>"4", "e"=>"5", "g"=>"6"}
.select{|k, v| ['b', 'e'].include?(k)}
```